# How to remove the unique id from the pyspark partitioned dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHEQl.png)

Above is the pyspark Dataframe.
I need to add a new column - "new_col", wherein I need to apply the below transformation-

1. when difference is greater than 0, then pick as many row_id as there are values in difference column from last within Team B partition
2. when difference is smaller than 0, then pick as many row_id as there are values in difference column from start within Team A partition
3. when difference is 0, then pick all row_id

for eg. If difference is 2, I need to pick values from last from Team B i.e. 4,5
similarly, if difference is -2, I need to pick values starting values from idx of Team A i.e. 1,2

`nested_window = Window().partitionBy('Team Name').orderBy('row_id')` 
`df = df.withColumn("new_col", F.when(df['difference'] > 0, F.last(df['row_id']).over(nested_window))) )`

I'm getting only the single last values, but not the multiples values when expected for difference>0

Comment: Can you provide your expected output for the above input?

Comment: Team Name row_id nested_row_id difference
Team B 4 2 2
Team B 5 3 2

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with `Window()`, but unable to get the multiple values. So, using UDF, you can achieve your requirement like below.

**Sample starting data:**

[image]

First, use group by and get the sorted array of `row_id` as a new column and store it in a new dataframe. Join this dataframe with starting dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sort_array,collect_list

#Create another dataframe with required row_id list
df2=df.groupBy("Team Name").agg(collect_list("row_id").alias("new_col")).withColumn("new_col",sort_array("new_col"))

#Join it with our dataframe
Joined_df = df.join(df2,  'Team Name',  'inner')
Joined_df.show()
```

It will give the dataframe like below.

[image]

Now, create a UDF for the case conditions and call it from the dataframe like below.

```
# Function to select values based on 'difference' returns the required array
@udf(ArrayType(IntegerType()))
def get_values(arr, diff):
    if diff > 0:
        return arr[-diff:]
    elif diff < 0:
        return arr[:abs(diff)]
    return arr

# Get the required row_id array using the udf
Joined_df.withColumn("new_col", get_values(Joined_df["new_col"], Joined_df["difference"])).show()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: , Could you pls help me with two changes here...
1#. Difference will remain same either + or - or 0. 
2#. If difference is positive, then need to pick values from last in ONLY Team B.
3#. If difference is negative, then need to pick values from start in ONLY Team A.

Comment: you can change the case conditions according to your requirement in UDF.